# Обязательное расчление союзов

Tags: пунктуация

Ссылок на правило или учебник нет. Чем обосновано следующее правило, и как его трактовать, — не понимаю, поэтому обращаюсь с вопросом к вам.

При включении первой части союза в однородные члены — расчление обязательно.

1) Как я понимаю, здесь одно предложение входит в сложносочиненное, и есть придаток.

**Сергей был недоволен от своего невезения и незнания, и от нечестного обращения чиновников, и оттого, что он очень надеялся на эту возможность.**

Если исходить из написанного  в правиле, а именно: при включении первой части расчленение обязательно, — значит, что вторая часть следующая после **оттого,что** не является однородной, а является придатком.

Получается, что группа однородных включает отрезок предложения
*"и от нечестного обращения чиновников, и оттого".* На этом группа заканчивается. Как так может быть?

Получается, что дальше идет придаток причины: *"оттого, что он очень надеялся на эту возможность".*

2) Может ли быть такое, что указательное тут выступает и как усилитель значения?
*И от нечестного обращения чиновников* (отчего?); *и оттого* (и отчего именно?), *что он очень надеялся на эту возможность*.
Я правильно задаю вопросы?

3) Может ли быть такое, что в составе предложения есть два разных типа связи: сочинительная и подчинительная в придатке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот вариант рассмотрен у Розенталя. Там сказано, что придаточное предложение может находиться в однородных отношениях с членами предложения, но при этом **однородный ряд (в том числе при наличии сочинительных союзов) включает только местоименную  часть** составного подчинительного союза, а придаточное со второй частью союза обособляется.

[§109. Пунктуация в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#%D0%B7_03)

К условиям расчленения сложного союза относятся: 4) **включение первой части (соотносительного слова) в ряд однородных членов**, например: Ромашов же краснел до настоящих слез **от своего бессилия и растерянности, и от боли** за оскорбленную Шурочку, **и оттого,** что ему сквозь оглушительные звуки кадрили не удавалось вставить ни одного слова... (Куприн).

Answer (score 0):

> получается, группа однородных включает отрезок предложения "и от
>   нечестного обращения чиновников, и оттого" - на этом группа
>   заканчивается? Как так может быть?

Это почему же это? Однородными являются члены целиком, а не только союзы. 
Здесь три однородных члена: "от своего невезения и незнания", "от нечестного обращения чиновников" и "оттого, что он очень надеялся на эту возможность". 
В последний однородный член входит придаточное.

Два последних имеют повторяющийся союз "и". Этого достаточно для выбора имеющейся пунктуации. Что же касается союзов, то да, эти члены присоединены с помощь союзов "от" и "оттого" (эти союзы и дают представление об однородности этих присоединяемых членов). Если попытаться подставить в этот ряд нерасчленённый "оттого что", то однородность станет сомнительной, это будет выглядеть так, как будто бы придаточное отвечает на другой вопрос.

Вот примерно этим и руководствовались, формулируя подобное правило.

Answer (score 0):

Sibilla, Мимоходов я ознакомился с вашмии ответами, и- посмотрел вашу....нашу [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#з_03](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#%D0%B7_03)

На самом деле - нечего сложного. Термин соотносительное слова сначала не был очень понятен, но потом, смог разобраться , что он обозначает. Вы мне помогли закрыть пробел в грамматике расчленения подчиненных.

Спасибо!